# What are some good resources for learning to develop VIM plugins?

Tags: plugins, vim

I am learning VIM and would like to try to hack on some VIM plugins, but can't seem to find any resources for learning the scripting language.  It seems like its called VIMscript, but I'm finding almost nothing useful on Google.  Does anyone have any recommendations for learning how to develop VIM plugins from scratch?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 41 of the VIM manual seems to be what I was looking for

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#script

Another well explained book

http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Vim_en:Scripting

Answer (score 4):

This is a nice starting point to write scripts for Vim:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-vim-script-1/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Old question here, but I'd like to make a supplementary.

I was searching an interactive VimL learning resource like [python_koans](https://github.com/gregmalcolm/python_koans) but failed and found this awesome tutorial: [learnvimscriptthehardway](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) by Steve Losh.

I'm following [this tutorial cloned from GitHub](https://github.com/sjl/learnvimscriptthehardway) and hooked on learning in Vim.

1. It's editable while reading in Vim.
2. I can yank the command by `"ayy` to register a and then run `:@a` to
   execute it directly.
3. I don't need to type or copy and paste so many examples manually.
4. The instructional design is awesome, really.

I changed the filename from number to title in [this repository](https://github.com/eduOS/learnvimscriptthehardway), making it better.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

It is called vimscript and also VimL on many resources (for example, on [github](http://github.com)). I do not know any resources about vimscript, but you may start from [documentation section of the official site](http://www.vim.org/docs.php). Or, learn like me: first, read the help (the entire eval.txt and options.txt files), remember something, try to write some script that you want and try to understand how other people's scripts are working.